# Is a universe with a very low speed of light possible?

Tags: physics, hard-science

In my universe, the speed of light is measured at 5m/s. Now, these aren't meters as we know them, since if *all* it was is just to change $c$, then the scale of everything else would change with it, and there'd be no measurable difference (at least from what I know, I may be wrong.) So instead, I've decided to change the orbital distance of an electron (and perhaps other leptons) to much, *much* larger than what they currently are (by a factor of ~$10^{8}$). This results in a universe where what *feels* like a meter is a fifth of lightsecond.

My question is, is this a plausible way of "reducing" the speed of light? Or would it just be impossible for atoms to form if electrons orbited that far away? If so, how could I do this instead?

Comment: In the [Bohr atomic model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bohr_model), the orbital radius for the electron in a hydrogen atom depends on (1) Coulomb's constant $1 / (4\pi \varepsilon_0)$, the elementary charge $e$, the mass of the electron $m_e$, and Planck's constant $\hbar$. To make the radius one hundred million times larger, one or more of these values must change dramatically, with rather drastic consequences. That universe would be very not-similar to ours.

Comment: I think we have a rule for "changing a fundamental constant" in questions.  I can't imagine either `physics` or `hard-science` would apply, though, since in such a universe, both of those would be so entirely different from our own that speculation would be pointless.

Comment: hmmm alright. so I guess this (very unoriginal) idea is probably impossible. maybe I should change the tags to allow for more leeway?

Comment: I'm reluctantly VTC-ing this question. I think it's an interesting question. The problem is that it's *too* interesting. If a question could have an answer that fills and entire book, then it's too open for this site. The consequences of such a large change to such a fundamental building block of the universe would be so wide and varied that we could write voluminous tomes on it and still not have a complete answer.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because See my other comment - too broad for us to answer.

Comment: honestly, fair enough. I didn't really realize the scope of the question

Comment: OP may be interested in this [SIMULATION](http://gamelab.mit.edu/games/a-slower-speed-of-light/) of a universe with a very slow light speed.

Comment: I can recall a short story in which the search for FTL was cancelled because they found the speed of light in hyperspace was Slower. No idea author/title.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because (a) it's impossible to expect a [tag:hard-science] answer to a [tag:science-fiction] question. (Please read the wiki for that tag... answers that fail the tag are *subject to deletion.*) (b) We have no impirical evidence that it's possible, plausible, or even fancifully possible to change the value of *c.* (c) Asking if something fictional is possible (meaning, I assume, "in the real world/universe") isn't worldbuilding. (see [help/on-topic].)

Comment: @SurpriseDog That's a super-cool simulation, but it's demonstrating a (so to speak) 5D idea in a 2D universe. Expressing the game in a nutshell, if the speed of light is no faster than your walking speed, then you will pass the reflected light on the object you're walking toward long before you get to that object. But the game doesn't deal with things like how gravity, electricity, magnetism, etc. must be redefined. It's a cool but ultimately *massive* simplification of the problem. But very educational, nonetheless. Cheers and +1 for the link.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it would be great over a Physics SE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Slow" is ultimately judged relative to how quickly we perceive the world and reason about it. That involves signals bouncing around in the brain, and those signals are light-speed limited.

For that reason, I don't think the speed of light can be very low, no matter how much you mess with the fundamental constants. If we were larger, we would think more slowly, so not only our meter but also our second would be larger, and the speed of light in m/s would still be a large number.

Comment: -1 for failing to meet the standard of the [tag:hard-science] tag.